# MapStruct inheritance and calling "this"

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have a denormalized database and a domain model that includes multiple classes. for example

```
class BMW {
  EngineConfiguration engineConfiguration;
  ModelMetadata modelMetadata;
  BodyConfiguration bodyConfiguration;
}

class CarsEntity{
  String modelName;
  Integer year...
  //etc. all fields, in same class
}
```

I would like to write MapStruct mappers for EngineConfiguration, ModelMetadata and BodyConfiguration and then when uniting them all in one mapper. Example

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
class EngineConfigurationMapper {
  
  @Mapping(... specific fields mapping goes here)
  EngineConfiguration mapToDomain(CarsEntity carsEntity);
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {EngineConfigurationMapper.class , ...})
class BMWMapper {
  BMW mapToDomain(CarsEntity carsEntity);
}
```

The problem is that my mappers are not working by default, BMWMapper does not have the calls to the others mappers and I've tried expression calling `this` like `expression="(engineConfigurationMapper.mapToDomain(this))" target = "engineConfiguration)` but the mappers are not included in the implementation.
How can I achieve this?
P.S.: MapperConfig is of no use as well

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you say `this` you mean the source entity, i.e. `carsEntity`.

In `Mapping#source` you can use the source parameter name, which means that you can do the following:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {EngineConfigurationMapper.class , ...})
class BMWMapper {

  @Mapping( target = "engineConfiguration", source = "carsEntity")
  @Mapping( target = "modelMetadata", source = "carsEntity")
  @Mapping( target = "bodyConfiguration", source = "carsEntity")
  BMW mapToDomain(CarsEntity carsEntity);
}
```